# Want to create a custom class of type Dictionary<int, T>

Tags: c#, generics, dictionary

I want to create a custom class that basically wraps a dictionary.

I want to add a property to it called Name.

I tried:

```
public class MyDictionary<int, T> : Dictionary<int, T>
{
        public string Name { get; set;}

}
```

Doesn't seem to be working, any ideas?

**Update**

THe error I'm getting is:

```
Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type
```

Comment: What, specifically, doesn't work about that?

Comment: `public class MyDictionary<T> : Dictionary<int, T>` - the `int` in the first part is not a type parameter, it is a type.

Answer (score 35):

The problem is with your declaration. Your custom class only needs a single type parameter, since the `int` type never varies:

```
public class MyDictionary<T> : Dictionary<int, T>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: probably because checked rules of stuckoverflow and figured out that answers including only code might be not popular here.

Comment: @V.7 is that better?

Answer (score 1):

We can create our custom dictionary class :

```
 public class Dict<TKey, UValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>>
    {
        private LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>>[]  _values;
        private int capacity;
        public Dict()
        {
            _values = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>>[15];
        }
        public int Count => _values.Length;

        public void Add(TKey key,UValue val)
        {
            var hash = GetHashValue(key);
            if(_values[hash]==null)
            {
                _values[hash] = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>>();
            }
            var keyPresent = _values[hash].Any(p => p.Key.Equals(key));
            if(keyPresent)
            {
                throw new Exception("Duplicate key has been found");
            }
            var newValue = new KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>(key, val);
            _values[hash].AddLast(newValue);
            capacity++;
            if(Count<= capacity)
            {
                ResizeCollection();
            }
        }

        private void ResizeCollection()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
        {
            var hash = GetHashValue(key);
            return _values[hash] == null ? false : _values[hash].Any(p => 
    p.Key.Equals(key));
        }

        public UValue GetValue(TKey key)
        {
            var hash = GetHashValue(key);
            return _values[hash] == null ? default(UValue) :
                _values[hash].First(m => m.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
        }
        public IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>> GetEnumerator()
        {
            return (from collections in _values
                    where collections != null
                    from item in collections
                    select item).GetEnumerator();
        }

        private int GetHashValue(TKey key)
        {
            return (Math.Abs(key.GetHashCode())) % _values.Length;
        }
        IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return this.GetEnumerator();
        }

        public UValue this[TKey key]
        {
            get
            {
                int h = GetHashValue(key);
                if (_values[h] == null) throw new KeyNotFoundException("Keys not found");
                return _values[h].FirstOrDefault(p=>p.Key.Equals(key)).Value;
            }
            set
            {
                int h = GetHashValue(key);
                _values[h] = new LinkedList<KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>>();
                _values[h].AddLast(new KeyValuePair<TKey, UValue>
                                                    (key,value));
            }
        }
    }

static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Dict<int, int> dict=new Dict<int, int>();
            dict.Add(-1, -1);
            dict.Add(1, -1);
            dict.Add(9, -1);
            dict.ContainsKey(9);
            dict.GetValue(9);
            dict[10] = 34;
            foreach(var item in dict)
            {`enter code here`
                Console.WriteLine(item.Key);
                Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
            }
            Console.WriteLine(dict[10]);
        }
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `MyDictionary<int, T>` - you use a type (`int`) instead of an identifier here, hence the error `Type parameter declaration must be an identifier not a type`.

If you use and identifier like `TKey` it'll work just fine:

```
public class MyDictionary<TKey, TValue> : Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

or if you want it to be a dictionary with only `int` as key:

```
public class MyDictionary<TValue> : Dictionary<int, TValue>
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```